# How to pass variables through the refetch() in react query?

Tags: react-query

This is my useQuery hook

```
  const { isLoading: isBskLoading, refetch: refetchBskData } = useQuery(
    "bskFixturesData",
    () => {
      instance.get(`/basketball/matches/${date}`).then((res) => res.data);
    },
    {
      onSuccess: (jsonData) => {
        setBskData(jsonData);
        setHasBskData(true);
      },
      refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
      enabled: false,
    }
  );
```

I want to call the `refetchBskData()` function from a different component in my project and I am able to do so, but I am unable to figure out a way to pass date variables through the `refetchBskData()` which can be accessed in the `useQuery` hook above.

This is my code which calls the `refetchBskData()`

```
  useEffect(() => {
    let date = new Date(location.state.date);
    let formattedDate = date.toLocaleDateString("en-GB");
    refetchBskData()
  }, [refetchBskData, location]);
```

Any ideas on how to pass the `formattedDate`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

useQuery is reactive like any other hook, so it watches changes in your render. If you will pass any state to the `queryKey` it should refetch the data automatically if variable changes. Don't be afraid to calculate location right before you use a hook, `react-query` caches any deps so don't handle this in `useEffect`.

```
      const [date, setDate] = React.useState(new Date())
      const { data } = useQuery(["test", date], ({ queryKey: [_key, date] }) => {
        return date
      })
    
      const handleAddYear = () => {
        const newDate = new Date(date.setFullYear(date.getFullYear() + 1))
        setDate(newDate)
      }
    
      return (
        <div>
          <button onClick={handleAddYear}>Press to add a year</button>
          <div>
            {data?.toISOString()}
          </div>
        </div>
      );
```

In you case you should do next:

```
export function useFetchBskData(date) {
  return useQuery(
    ["bskFixturesData", date],
    async ({ queryKey: [_key, date] }) => {
      const response = await instance.get(`/basketball/matches/${date}`);
      return response.data;
    },
    {
      refetchOnWindowFocus: false
    }
  );
}
```

Or:

```
const date = new Date(location.state.date);
const formattedDate = date.toLocaleDateString("en-GB");

const { isLoading: isBskLoading } = useQuery(
    ["bskFixturesData", date],
    ({ queryKey: [_key, date] }) => {
      return instance.get(`/basketball/matches/${date}`).then((res) => res.data);
    },
    {
      onSuccess: (jsonData) => {
        setBskData(jsonData);
        setHasBskData(true);
      },
      refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
      enabled: false,
    }
  );
```

Comment: In the first method where you pass the date as a payload, I am unable to call the API with the `refetch().` How can I call the API?

Comment: Show me the code. It should work as usuall const { data, refetch } = useFetchBskData(date)

Comment: I am not particularly good with using **sandbox**, but I tried to put together my code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-http-wp8vn8?file=/src/Helpers/useFetchBskData.jsx).
Please let me know if there's any mistake I am making or so.

Comment: Sorry, I made a little mistake. There should be { queryKey: [_key, date] }. Let me update the answer

Comment: This works, thank you so much. I had a really hard time figuring on how to achieve this.